# How to make a random name matcher with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my first year getting into code as a hobby. For my personal side project I want to make a date-matcher (not for a friend haha). This is mainly for me trying to get a better understanding for python structures.

To summarize: People fill 2 lists of names and the matcher returns back a list with random matches. (NO DUPLICATES)

Also, coming with these rules:
1. I want make every 'user'(name) choose between they are (Open, Not Interested, Taken) and match the strings accordingly.

2. When the are more items in a certain list, left over strings get printed out too

3 [Optional] When users fill in their name, they can fill in a certain 'preference string', making it a higher chance to be matched together with that string.

I'm kinda stuck at the first phase, this is what I have:

```
import random
VNamen=["Sarah","Annelotte","Kelsey","Mika","Ilse","Yara","Sjouke"]
MNamen=["Kelvin","Xander","Kolten","Ezekiel","Misael","Landon","Noel"]
VR= random.choices(VNamen)
MR= random.choices(MNamen)
print(VR, "together with",MR)
```

1. How do I randomly match the strings together?
2. How do I remove the duplicates in the resulting list
3. Maybe some suggestions on the rest of the functions above?

I hope someone has the time for this (for me) complicated question!

Greetings,
Quinten

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, could you elaborate the objective that you want to achieve by the code, you are just matching the strings by randomly picking them up

Comment: @dper I don't know whether this makes it more clear, I;ve added some certain questions. And yes the code isn't really adding something but I m working on it on the go.

Comment: String matching is a pretty straight forward task... go through this article and it will give you an idea for the same.. https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now, there are things like "[re](https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html)" that i would suggest (like dper did in the comment of your code), but if you want to do it with your own code, would suggest using `random.choice(list)` after importing random (which you  have done) which will chose a random person from that list, do this with both lists, and put them(as in the two given names) together into another list and remove their names from the original lists, do this until one of the lists is empty, then print out everything in the not empty list.

Woah that was a lot of lists...

preference settings would be a little more complicated, you would have to use a list, which goes everywhere the name used to go, and in that list there would be all the information they have, but this way it would be impossible(as far as i am aware) to change the likelihood of getting a certain name.

if you would like me to actually show you it with your code, comment and ask me to do so, but i would suggest giving it a go yourself (if you chose to do it this way that is).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do some python-puzzling to solve this with random.choice.